# how to set custom font to one of the TextView's in ListView item using adapters?

Tags: c#, java, android, xml-parsing

how to set custom font to one of the TextView's in ListView item using adapters?

I used this code but am getting runtime exception at **getView** method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.hands.daily.duas.database.MyDbClass;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.Typeface;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    static int i=11;

    private Activity activity;

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    First fst=new First();

  //  public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    String urlString="";

   MyDbClass mdbclass;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

         data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        activity = a;

        data=list;

        inflater=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

    }
    public int getCount() {

        return data.size();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;

    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;

        if(convertView==null)

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.duas_rowlist, null);

        TextView duatv = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); // duatv

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/Molot.otf");

        duatv.setTypeface(tf);

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview

       // String eventName1=song.get(First.Duas).toString();

        duatv.setTextSize(i);

     duatv.setText(song.get(First.Duas));

        return vi;

    }

}
```

Comment: post LogCat result when app is crashing

Answer (score 0):

```
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Molot.otf");
```

that's probably why. you shouldn't be getting a context from the convertview in an adapter even if it did have one. This sort of thing belongs in your adapter's constructor taking the context of the activity passed being passed in. i reformatted your constructor as well.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Typeface tf;

public LazyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    this.data = data;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Molot.otf");
    // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
}

......
```